# Using For each loop without try-catch in Visual basic 2012

Tags: vb.net

I have this simple code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim strFriends(4) As String

Private Sub ArrayElement_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ArrayElement.Click
    ClearList()


    'Try
    For Each item As String In strFriends
        lstFriends.Items.Add(item)
    Next
    'Catch
    'End Try
End Sub

Private Sub ClearList()
    lstFriends.Items.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    strFriends(0) = "tom"
    strFriends(1) = "kate"
    strFriends(2) = "bill"
    strFriends(3) = "harry"
End Sub
```

End Class

If the try-catch is removed, i get `System.ArgumentNullException` is it compulsory to use try catch block to use For Each?

Comment: Keep in mind that your array has _five_ elements, not four.  Your Form1_Load method does not populate the fifth value.

Comment: My array is also size 4 :) <code>Dim strFriends(4) As String</code>

Comment: That array is size 5.  In VB, the 4 is the _upper bound_ not the size of the array.  You have indices 0 - 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(item) Then
    ' Add item
End If
```

UPDATE:

You can check to see if the array has anything in it, like this:

```
If strFriends.Length > 0 Then
    ' Do something with array
End If
```

Comment: Is there a way to check if an array is not empty? instead of item by item, check array is not empty in the beginning and then continue using the array?

Comment: Yes, see UPDATE in answer. You should still check to see that individual items are not null or empty though.

Comment: The method exists, but doesn't work if i use it before the for each loop. Guess checking individual item is the only way.

Comment: You can have an array with length > 0 that contains null elements. You're better off checking item by item. If you really don't want to add any of the elements if any of them are null, then use Any (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a 5 element array: `Dim strFriends(4) As String`. In Vb.NET the number represents the max index on the array, not the number of elements.

But you're declaring only 4 elements. So in the foreach block, the last element is the default value for strings, which is `Nothing`, being unable to add it to the listview (or whatever).

You can check for every item on the array to be valid, like others suggested, or correct your code.

Try this, for example:

```
strFriends = New String() {"tom", "kate", "bill", "harry"}
```

You can use a List, too:

```
Dim strFriends As New List(Of String)()

strFriends.Add("tom")
strFriends.Add("kate")
strFriends.Add("bill")
strFriends.Add("harry")
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can check each item before adding. You are also not filling the last element and that is the reason for the exception.

```
If item IsNot Nothing Then
   'add item
End If
```

Comment: yes that works. I find it a bit strange though. Java doesn't require such a check and i think even C# doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

No, a for each loop does not require a try block. Using try-catch for flow control is a bug. Instead, test to ensure that elements are not Nothing before adding them.